# tx_time_get() always returns 0 in threadx module manager

Tags: time, threadx, azure-rtos

I am trying to calculate the time ticks, however tx_time_get() always returns 0 wherever I put it in modules or module manager of ThreadX
E.G:

```
    ULONG start_time, current_time=0, cycle_time=0;
    start_time= tx_time_get();
    current_time=tx_time_get();
    cycle_time= current_time-start_time;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the program did not reach the minimum resolution of the system clock which is by default 10 MS, so I need to decrease the resolution by changing `TX_TIMER_TICKS_PER_SECOND` in order to calculate the time spent on a certain block. However, it will decrease the performance.

[Ref](https://renesasrulz.com/embedded-system-platform/synergy/f/forum/6273/how-reliable-is-tx_get_time-function)